# Deleting Meeting Requests made by terminated users

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

Need to delete the meeting requests made by terminated users from all the conference rooms for multiple terminated users at a time.

below is the script which i built to delete the meetings requests for two terminated users from all the conference rooms. i used `OR` operator if i want to delete the meetings for two terminated users(kind:calendar from:sasi OR Kalai). How can i add more than two terminated users at a time? i have more than 500 terminated users to delete their meetings requests from all the conference rooms.

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Preparing" -Status "Retrieving mailbox list" -PercentComplete 0
$rooms=get-mailbox -recipienttypedetails roommailbox -resultsize unlimited -warningaction:silentlycontinue| where {$_.name -notlike "*test*"}

$count=$rooms.count

foreach($room in $rooms)

{


    $i=$i+1
    $percentage=$i/$count*100


    Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting mailbox details" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $Count - $room" -PercentComplete $percentage

$room | search-mailbox -searchquery "kind:calendar from:sasi OR Kalai" -targetmailbox sankar_munirathinam@domain.com -targetfolder "Deleting Meeting" -deletecontent -force

}
```

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand the above correctly, you'd do the following?  and you can take the "deletecontent -force" if this is merely investigative?

```
Write-Progress -Activity "Preparing" -Status "Retrieving mailbox list" -PercentComplete 0
$rooms=get-mailbox -recipienttypedetails roommailbox -resultsize unlimited -    
warningaction:silentlycontinue| where {$_.name -notlike "*test*"}

$count=$rooms.count
$TerminatedUsers = Get-Content .\TerminatedUsersList.txt
foreach ($User in $TerminatedUsers) {
foreach($room in $rooms)

{


$i=$i+1
$percentage=$i/$count*100


Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting mailbox details" -Status "Processing mailbox $i of $Count -
$room" -PercentComplete $percentage

$room | search-mailbox -searchquery "kind:calendar from:$($user)" -targetmailbox    
administrator@domain.com -targetfolder "Deleting Meeting" -deletecontent -force

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can actually answer this for you!  My first answer (that I can remember) on stack:)

You should put the terminated users' usernames (or some other identifier) in a text file, then insert a new line below your line

`$count=$rooms.count`

that is

`$TerminatedUsers = Get-Content .\TerminatedUsersList.txt`.

Then add another line that is

`foreach ($User in $TerminatedUsers) {`

Then add a final closing curly brace `}` to the very end of your script.

Finally, change your `from:sasi OR Kalai` to `from:$($User)`

This will loop through each of the terminated users, and for each one of them, it will search all of the room mailboxes for their meetings.

I hope this makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet tried it yet, but I just found that the Exchange module has a command to delete meetings. The one caveat I see is that it needs to be done while the account is still active.

[Remove-CalendarEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-calendarevents?view=exchange-ps)