# O365 search-mailbox email type error

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, azure-powershell

I've a need to delete meeting requests made by terminated users. I've been following the script at [Deleting Meeting Requests made by terminated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524919/deleting-meeting-requests-made-by-terminated-users), but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Please adjust the email type. Make sure the email type is supported.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParserException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=BLUPR0501MB1828,RequestId=ea14893a-dd30-4808-aeb5-0e85cbe7eb3b,TimeStamp=6/7/2016 2:21:27 PM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-ParserException] 95B6EDE8
+ PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

My command line is as such (with edits, of course):

```
$room | search-mailbox -SearchQuery "kind:calendar AND from:$($user)" -targetmailbox adminuser@domain.com -TargetFolder "deleted meetings"
```

where $user is the UPN of a user, and $room has been extracted from a query.

I've looked and can't seem to determine where the cause of the error is.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. AQS syntax is incorrect. "kind:calendar" should be "kind:meetings"