# The term 'Search-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet Exchange Online Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365, exchange-server

I am currently working on a script that would delete meeting requests from terminated employees of the organization. I found this one as a reference ([Deleting Meeting Requests made by terminated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524919/deleting-meeting-requests-made-by-terminated-users)) and i can't get it to work for me because of my error.

this is my script

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"


$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber
#Enter-PSSession $session

$rooms = Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails RoomMailbox -ResultSize Unlimited  

$count=$rooms.count
$TerminatedUsers = Get-Content D:\Work\SHAR78\resignedEmployees.txt

Write-Host "count of rooms " $count

foreach ($user in $TerminatedUsers) {

   Write-Host "terminated user" $user

    foreach($room in $rooms) {

        $room | Search-Mailbox -searchquery "kind:calendar from:$($user)" -targetmailbox admin@admin.com -TargetFolder "SearchData" -logonly -loglevel full
        #-targetmailbox administrator@domain.com -targetfolder "Deleting Meeting" -deletecontent -force

    }
}
```

i am connected to Exchange Online so im not sure why Search-Mailbox is not being imported. my account has an Owner permission as well.

Comment: Did you check out what is being imported from the session? Maybe it's not exposed which might be because you don't have sufficient permissions?

Comment: This cmdlet is available in on-premises Exchange Server 2016 and in the cloud-based service. So , could you please use get-command and see if it is available.

Comment: Hi @Seth what permission does my account need? i checked using get-command and i cant find search-Mailbox. i only see Search-MailboxAuditLog.

Comment: @RanadipDutta i used Get-Commant what i got for Search does not include Search-Mailbox. it has search-AdminAuditLog then Search-MailboxAuditLog

Comment: Exactly. That means you do not have the cmdlet available. This is only for exchange 2016. So you have to see some workaround for this in lower version. :) But as per my knowledge In Exchange 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1), you can use the Search-Mailbox

Comment: I have posted and answer, you can check that . It should do your work. @PageF.P.T

Comment: @RanadipDutta thanks, may i know what is the default exchange for office 365 outlook?

Comment: If you buy a new Office365 service now it will be Exchange 2013 CU1 which is the latest  version of Exchange that time - older Office365 organisations will be a mix of 2010 and 2013 depending on when they were purchasing.
NOw i think newer versions available. Not sure exactly

Comment: According to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876958(v=exchg.150).aspx) you would need to be in the (default) group "Discovery Management" or "Organization Management". Alternatively you could assign the "Mailbox search" role to a custom group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you do not have the cmdlet available. So check the proper version.

Please do the following and see:

Create "**Mailbox Import-Export Management**" role group and be a member of it.

To create the role group use:

`New-RoleGroup "Mailbox Import-Export Management" -Roles "Mailbox Import Export"`

To add the member:
`Add-RoleGroupMember "Mailbox Import-Export Management" -Member`

Apart from that if you want to search then you can use like this:

```
Get-mailbox | Export-Mailbox –AllContentKeywords "thekeysyouwant" –TargetMailbox Administrator –TargetFolder 'foldername'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I now get this: The term 'Export-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: I believe some issue with the pssnapin of exchange. Could you please try in another box and check

Comment: Try this link. [LINK](http://www.aurelp.com/tag/solved-export-mailbox-and-import-mailbox-commands-not-recognized/)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help i have already resolved it although i am not really sure how i did that i'm guessing its on the permission. but thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @PageF.P.T:  Please upvote / accept the answer if it helps you :)